# Trying to switch from using 'append' to 'appendto' that have [0] and variables

Tags: jquery, append

I'm switching from using 'append' to 'appendto' because I want to move the entire div, not just the text inside the div. It's difficult because there are [0] and variables.

The specific line of code I'm working on changing is:

```
$("#section-"+section_count)[0].append($(this).html());
```

I'm a beginner coder and tried a few codes, like the ones below, but it doesn't work. How do I write this properly?

```
$(this).appendTo($("#section-"+section_count)[0]);
```

---

What I'm trying to accomplish is for the result to look like this:

```html
<div id="newsection">
   <section>
     <div> A </div>
     <div> B </div>
     <div> C </div>
     <div> D </div>
   </section>
</div>
```

Currently it looks like this:

```html
<div id="newsection">
   <section>
     "A"
     "B"
     "C"
     "D"
   </section>
</div>
```

---

There's a lot of moving around because I'm trying to apply this in WordPress. Here is the whole code if it may help:

```html
<section id="originalsection">
    <div> A </div>
    <div> B </div>
    <div> C </div>
    <div> D </div>
</section>
<div id="newsection"> </div>
```

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
      var div_count = 0;
      var section_count = 0;

      $('section#originalsection div').each(function () {
         if ($("#section-"+section_count).length == 0) {
            $('#newsection').append('<section id="section-'+section_count+'"></section>');
         }

      $("#section-"+section_count)[0].append($(this).html());
      /**** CODE ABOVE TRYING TO CHANGE THIS TO APPENDTO ****/
      $(this).remove();

      div_count += 1;
      if (div_count > 3) {
          div_count = 0;
          section_count += 1;
      }  
      });
   });
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to move the entire element, why not just change it to `$("#article-"+section_count).append(this);` ?  Seems like you're over complicating things in a major way

Comment: The point here being, an element can only have a single parent in the DOM.  If the element (`this` in this case) is already attached to the DOM, when you append it to a different parent, it will be moved, not duplicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation.
I have a better understanding of how this, DOM, and the elements work together now.
When I add your code to my code, everything disappears.
Why could this be?
(also, there were a few errors in my example I fixed; Mainly changing the ID #article to #section)

Comment: The only line you changed was `$("#section-"+section_count)[0].append($(this).html());` correct?

Comment: I changed that one and also
“if ($("#article-"+section_count).length == 0) {"  
to
“if ($("#section-"+section_count).length == 0) {“

Comment: It worked!!! I just had to remove the "$(this).remove();" code. That makes sense because I was probably removing the div that was just appended. Thank you so much!! Bless your help :)